# Обработка error'ов с помощью if

Tags: python

Возникла такая проблема, мне нужно обработать событие, но его нельзя сформулировать ни в python, ни в поисковике. Из-за этого возникает error. Как мне обработать определённую ошибку, с помощью if?
Пример:

```py
if 'ошибка/код ошибки':
    print('возникла ошибка: ', 'ошибка/код ошибки')
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Для этого есть конструкция try...except
https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/isklyucheniya-v-python-konstrukciya-try-except-dlya-obrabotki-isklyuchenij.html

Answer (score 1):

Для обработки исключений предназначена конструкция try - except. Делать это через if довольно странно. Если только проверять типы данных, но возможность сделать это зависит от задачи, которую вы решаете

Comment: try - except тормозит код

Comment: @gfd2  как и любой другой способ обработки ошибки.

Comment: @gfd2 1 - насколько по сравнению с if? 2 - как вы с помощью if обработаете исключение, брошенное сторонней функцией?

Comment: @insolor когда я работал в проекте связанный с камерами как раз использовался try - except для определения что камера в сети и Фпс на видео был очень маленький. Поменяли на несколько if, и фпс выросла так, как будто нет ни какой проверки.

Comment: @gfd2 ну, если ванговать, то у вас видимо была обертка над сторонней динамической библиотекой, и первоначально проверку вы реализовали через выброс исключения, а потом упростили, переделав на проверку кода возврата. Это не всегда возможно. Если используется какая-то сторонняя готовая Python библиотека, которая кидает исключения, а не возвращает коды результата, то придется использовать именно try-except, или переделывать библиотеку, что может быть накладно.

Comment: @gfd2 Вообще выглядит странно. `try-except` действительно тормозит, но не до такой степени, чтобы это было так критически заметно. Наверняка дело было в чём-то другом. Я вот даже проверил, если поставить `try-except` внутрь длинного цикла, который ничего не делает, то да - можно затормозить код на треть. Если ставить снаружи такого цикла - вообще никакого эффекта. И если цикл будет не пустой, а что-то делающий - опять же никакого эффекта торможения невозможно уже заметить.